# Get normal JavaScript array of dom elements from jquery select

Tags: jquery

From the following jQuery command I get several input elements:

$("#main :input")

Now I need those elements as a normal JavaScript array with the normal DOM elements.

In order to get this, do I have to create this array by myself using:

```
var normalList = [];
$("#main :input").each(function() {
  normalList.push(this);
})
```

or is there some shorter way?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) - with no arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sweetArray = [].slice.call($("#main :input"));
```

Here you go.